# How to send the text box value to struts2 action class from ajax?

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have tried to send the text box value to struts action class method to process the out put.
Html form:

```
<form action="" id="finder">
<textarea id="productsTextArea" name="product"></textarea>
 </form>
```

Jquery :

```
jQuery.ajax({
 url : '<s:url action="part" method="finder" />',
 data : product,
 dataType : 'json',
 success : function(data){
```

Action class:

I have getters and setters method the class and trying to access product variable.

Note : I'm able to get the response. but i have problem in sending data to server only.

Comment: what is `product` in `data : product` ? Is it a variable or are you expecting it'll be the value of the textarea ?

Comment: expecting the value of textarea...

Comment: ok then you should probably do this `data : {"product" : $("#productsTextArea").val()}` and see.

Comment: Great , its working good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting it as answer.

ok then you should probably do this

```
data : {"product" : $("#productsTextArea").val()}
```